# Позитивный и негативный просмотр назад

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Что не так с этим регулярным выражением ?

- Ничего не находит

Я пытаюсь получить группу со словом `рандом` перед которым есть или отсутствует любой символ, кроме перевода строки.

Шаблон - если есть любой символ перед `рандом`:

```
\|((?<=.)рандом)\|
```

Шаблон - если нет какого либо символа перед `рандом`:

```
\|((?<!.)рандом)\|
```

Набросок:

```
|рандом|
|1рандом|
|2рандом|
|3рандом|
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, не только кроме перевода строки, но и символа `|`: `\|([^|]*(?<![^|\n\r])рандом)\|` / `\|([^|]*(?<=[^|\n\r])рандом)\|`. Поясните, что в каждом конкретном случае нужно получить и почему.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew получается что условие просмотра назад заходит и за саму группу в который объявлен ?

Comment: Блоки просмотра проверяют найденный текст. Если у вас `\|((?<=.)рандом)\|`, то это всегда TRUE, так как `|` находится с помощью `.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Понял свою ошибку. Спасибо! Думал не выходят за группу, оказывается проверяют full match. Штудировал 3 документа по регулярным выражениям, никто про это не написал(